# Is it possible to use Environment/System Variables in Content Delivery config files?

Tags: content-delivery, 2013, configuration

I am trying to create environment-neutral configuration files to enable all developers on a project to have a working, local CD environment without having to customize configuration.

The main problem is that everything on the server is in the D:\ drive, but some developers do not have a D:\ drive, or do not want to use this or C:\ for their local environments.

I noticed that you can put environment variables in the logback.xml file to, for example generalize the log file path:

```
<property name="log.folder" value="${TRIDION_HOME}/log/staging"/>
```

So long as each developer has a TRIDION_HOME environment variable, the logs will be created in the log sub directory.

I tried this for the license file location in cd_storage_conf.xml:

```
<License Location="${TRIDION_HOME}/config/cd_licenses.xml"/>
```

But it doesnt work. I see it fails to load the license in the log:

> 2013-10-02 08:55:19,670 WARN  StorageManagerFactory - Attempt to use
>   license file ${TRIDION_HOME}/config/cd_licenses.xml failed, file does
>   not exist. A LicenseException will be thrown.

Is there another way to inject variables into the Content Delivery configuration files?

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve this might be to have everyone run the same set-up scripts. In the example scripts at [Tridion Practice](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/ScriptedProvisioningOfTridionContentDelivery), the Master Setup script begins by setting the following locations, which everyone can set appropriately for their own system.

```
$InetPub = "C:\inetpub"
$InstallerHome = "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Tridion"
$TempLocation = "C:\Users\Administrator\ScriptTempLocation"
$stagingVisitorsSiteName = $testPrefix + "staging.visitorsweb.local"
$stagingUploadSiteName = $testPrefix + "upload.staging.visitorsweb.local"
$stagingIncomingDir = "C:\Tridion\incoming\stagingvisitorsweb"
$liveVisitorsWebSiteName = $testPrefix + "www.visitorsweb.local"
$liveUploadWebSiteName = $testPrefix + "upload.visitorsweb.local"
$liveIncomingDir = "c:\Tridion\Incoming\visitorsweb"
$previewDbServerName = "DATABASE_SERVER"
$brokerServerName = "DATABASE_SERVER"
$previewDatabaseName = "Tridion_XPM"
$previewDbUserName = "TridionBrokerUser"
$previewDbPassword = "Tridion1"
$SqlJdbcJar = "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sqljdbc4.jar"
$cdLicensePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\config\cd_licenses.xml"
$LogDir = "C:\Tridion\Log"
```

Comment: Thanks Dom. In this case we are not actually installing CD on the local dev machines, but doing a combination of XCopy from the server (for published files) and checkout from SVN (for web application, references and config). For the moment I am working around it by removing the License node from the config and putting the cd_licenses.xml file in the config folder of each web app.

Comment: The scripts might also help there. You should be able to copy/paste some code to manipulate the configs as you wish.